# Doing CRUD on the DA Ledger through a gRPC client

Tags: php, grpc, daml

I am in the process of writing a DA Ledger client application.  It's going slow because the API documentation does not explain how to combine the provided services to do simple Create, read, update, and delete on the Ledger.
For example there is no simple service that allows the client to read all contacts from a given party directly.  First the client needs to get the ledger id, and then (I think) the package id.  etc.  There is a service to read active contracts, but what about inactive contracts? 
It would be helpful to have some documentation that explains and demonstrates how to combine calls to the various services to (for example):

- Read all contracts for a given party
- Exercize a choice on a given contract
- Create a new contract

My application is being written in php.  I don't necessarily need examples in php but I just want to know how do use the provided services to accomplish simple tasks.

Comment: For generic questions on how to use the API, I believe you'd be better off asking on the DAML Driven Slack channel. https://digitalasset-dev.slack.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read all contracts for a given party**

A DAML Ledger is an inherently event-driven system. As such it doesn't provide query access like a traditional database. Instead, your application subscribes to the [TransactionService](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/ledger-api-introduction/proto-docs.html#transactionservice) using the [GetTransactionsRequest](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/ledger-api-introduction/proto-docs.html#gettransactionsrequest) and specifying [LEDGER_BEGIN](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/ledger-api-introduction/proto-docs.html#com-digitalasset-ledger-api-v1-ledgeroffset) as the `begin` offset. This will deliver you all `Created` and `Archived` events that happened since the ledger was started. In your application you can consume these events to build up a representation (in-memory or persisted) of the ledger, which you can then query conveniently. For example, you could populate a dictionary by contract type, adding an entry for each `Created` event and removing it again when an `Archived` event is received.

**Create contracts or exercise choices**

There are two ways to do this:

- Submit a create or exercise command via `Submit` on the [CommandSubmissionService](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/ledger-api-introduction/proto-docs.html#commandsubmissionservice) and wait for a success or error message on the [CommandCompletionService](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/ledger-api-introduction/proto-docs.html#commandcompletionservice). Note that receiving such command completion message only confirms that the command could be successfully received by the ledger. It will not contain any effects (create and archive events) from that command. These you will again receive on the `TransactionService` mentioned above.
- Submit a create or exercise command via `SubmitAndWait` on the [CommandService](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/ledger-api-introduction/proto-docs.html#commandservice). This service combines command submission and completion in a synchronous call to the server-side, and will therefore only return once the command has been accepted or rejected by the server. It is usually more convenient to use this way of command submission as it takes care of some of the asynchronous event handling required in the previous method.

Note that you can obtain the contract id required to exercise choices from your ledger representation built up using the `TransactionService` mentioned above.

Comment: I don't see any mention in your message of the package id or the ledger id.  I am having trouble getting the package id because there is no daml_lf for php.  How do I parse the archive_payload from the GetPackageResponse?

Comment: You are correct, the DAML-LF protos are currently not shipped as part of the SDK, but we plan to include them soon. In the meantime you can find them here: https://digitalassetsdk.bintray.com/DigitalAssetSDK/com/digitalasset/daml-lf-archive-protos/13.0.0/daml-lf-archive-protos-13.0.0.zip

Comment: I downloaded the DML-LF protos from the link.  I don't think they are what I'm looking for.  What I wanted to do was to access the library of functions that are needed to parse the out of the archive_payload that comes in the 'GetPackageResponse' object.  I can see from the java bindings and the node.js bindings it is called DAML_LF.  For example `DamlLf.ArchivePayload.parseFrom(getPackageResponse.getArchivePayload());'  from 'PingPongMain.java'.  I don't think this function relies on the DA Ledger server and thereofre is not related to any .proto file.

Comment: Anyway I think I can get away without the DAML_LF functions and simply use the last package that was returned from ListPackages().  I can hard code the Module Name and Entity Name from the my DAML code.  If so, no parsing of the archive_payload is required.  (As they do on their Webinar titled "Using the Ledger API to Integrate with the Digital Asset Platform" )